# what's the difference between tf.nn.conv2d with strides = 2 and tf.nn.max_pool with 2x2 pooling?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, training-data

As mentioned above, both

> tf.nn.conv2d with strides = 2

and

> tf.nn.max_pool with 2x2 pooling

can reduce the size of input to half, and I know the output may be different, but what I don't know is that affect the final training result or not, any clue about this, thanks.

Comment: c comprehensive analysis is given here, the effect of pooling vs conv2d with stride https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.01983.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both your examples assume we have a `[height, width]` kernel applied with strides `[2,2]`. That means we apply the kernel to a 2-D window of size `[height, width]` on the 2-D inputs to get an output value, and then slide the window over by 2 either up or down to get the next output value.

In both cases you end up with 4x fewer outputs than inputs (2x fewer in each dimension) assuming `padding='SAME'`

The difference is how the output values are computed for each window:

**conv2d**

- the output is a linear combination of the input values times a weight for each cell in the `[height, width]` kernel
- these weights become trainable parameters in your model

**max_pool**

- the output is just selecting the maximum input value within the `[height, width]` window of input values
- there is no weight and no trainable parameters introduced by this operation

Answer (score 0):

The results of the final training could actually be different as the convolution multiplies the tensor by a filter, which you might not want to do as it takes up extra computational time and also can overfit your model as it will have more weights.